# if tab fadeIn, redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

I have a tab:

```
<div id=tab1> ... </div>
```

And I want to do, if tab1 fadeIn, then redirect.

How would I do it? I would imagine something likes this:

```
if $('#tab1').fadeIn(function(){
        window.location = "http://google.com"
});
```

Comment: Do you want to detect or trigger a fadein?

Comment: detect a fadeIn, then perform the redirect

Comment: You can't really directly do that

Comment: What you seem to be looking for is a fadeIn event to bind an action to (in this case, redirection). As far as I know, this does not exist. Instead I would suggest looking at any calls you make to fade that element in, and trigger the redirect action accordingly. This would essentially require you to manually manage your fadeIn event

Comment: What's another logic way of doing it?

Comment: @Adu I am fading in as follow: var ref = jQuery(this).attr('href').split('#')[1];. I have around 30 tabs so I can't think of another way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you mean is if the tab is hidden go somewhere then this syntax could work:

```
if ($("#tab1").is(":hidden")) {
 window.location = "http://www.google.com/";
}
```

Comment: Worked. I wanted the opposite so I used :visible instead. Thanks alot

Comment: How can I set delay to it? if ($("#tab1").is(":visible")).delay(1000) ?

Comment: if ($("#tab1").is(":hidden")) { window.setTimeout(function() { window.location = "";}, 1000); }